Scraping Yahoo Finance Summary Table with Cheerio
I'm trying to scrape "1y Target Est, 1,140.21" from Yahoo Finance Summary Table, as marked in red.

I tried this code, but am getting no data.  Inspecting the tag, I see "1,1140.21" is under <td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)" data-test="ONE_YEAR_TARGET_PRICE-value">1,140.21</td>.  So I thought this code should work, but doesn't.  What should I change?
function test() {

  const url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/NVDA/'
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true }).getContentText();
  const $ = Cheerio.load(res);
  const targetPrice = $('td[data-test="ONE_YEAR_TARGET_PRICE-value"]').text().toString();
  console.log(targetPrice)
}


I'm not sure where you're getting your selector from (I don't see it on the page at all), but this works for me:
function test() {
  const url = "<Your URL>";
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const $ = Cheerio.load(response.getContentText());
  const targetPrice = $('[data-field="targetMeanPrice"]').text();
  console.log(targetPrice); // => 1,140.21
}

Should pulling it from the HTML like this fail, there's also a raw JSON payload in a <script type="application/json" data-sveltekit-fetched data-url="..."> tag you can use.
See also Parsing Yahoo finance data

Oh great, it's working!   Thanks a lot.  I like to learn about your method.  Is there any tutorial so I can lean.

I looked at view-source:your_url, then hit Ctrl+F and typed in the data you want, then grabbed the "best" selector for the element (where "best" is defined by a guesstimate heuristic of something uniquely identifiable and likely stable, but not overly rigid and prone to breaking if the HTML structure changes).

I was checking tags with Inspect in Google Chrome.  What browser are you using?

Firefox, but it doesn't matter. Inspect is often inaccurate because it shows the DOM after JS has run. Making a fetch request only pulls down the basic HTML page, not scripts. view-source: gives you the text you actually get when you fetch the page with a plain HTTP request like you're doing. If the data isn't there, then see How can I scrape pages with dynamic content using node.js?

Yea, from Firefox I see what you explained.   I learned a key method from you.  Appreciated a lot.
